# Handling 2 sets of radio buttons using the attribute checked and unchecked

Tags: jquery

I am developing a mobile application and I have a click function in jQuery that applies a class to a set of radio buttons and removes that class from other radio buttons on the page.  I now have the use case where I have two sets of radio buttons, and now it the class removes all radio buttons not just the radio buttons in the current set.

I have setup a demo on JSFiddle which has two sets of radio buttons and you can see how they seem to be attached somehow, and I want to keep them inclusive.  Hopefully this makes since, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/qxV9c/1/)

Here is the jQuery code, check out the rest on JSFiddle.

```
$('.form-radios label').attr('checked', 'unchecked');

$(".form-radios label").click(function(){
       $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').addClass('checked');
       $('label').not(this).removeClass('checked');
});​
```

Comment: I don't quite get what the question is? Could you rephrase/highlight your question?

Comment: What you need to do is, if the radios are related use `name="group[]"` and filter `class=checked` on those elements only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".form-radios label").click(function(){
       $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').addClass('checked')
              .siblings('label').removeClass('checked');
});​
```

`siblings` will get only elements which share the same parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/qxV9c/2/

EDIT:  With the new structure:

```
$(".form-radios label").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.closest(".form-radios").find("label").removeClass('checked');
    $this.attr('checked', 'checked').addClass('checked');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qxV9c/5/

Comment: I see that you have siblings broken down on a new line.  What is the purpose for this?  I see the example working in JSFiddle, but I can't get it working in my use case.  Basically it's adding the checked class, but does not remove it form the others.

Comment: It's just for readability.  Does your real html structure match the one you posted?

Comment: I'm sorry I did leave out a containing div.  http://jsfiddle.net/qxV9c/4/  Updated the HTML and your JS

Comment: That makes a big difference.  Use @minitech's solution.  `closest` is the way to go with that structure.  Though I will add a slightly different version also using `closest`.  Probably minor, but reversing the order of what your'e doing and avoiding the call to `not` should be slightly more efficient.

Comment: What is the reason for moving "this" into a variable?

Comment: Each time you call `$(...)` you're making a call to jquery.  There's no reason to call it multiple times, so you save the variable and re-use it.  With `this` it's not that important, but with a complex selector it's one of the biggest improvements you can make to performance.  I could have avoiding this all together and just chained everything using `.end()`, but I find that to be pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Just find the closest parent element instead of searching everywhere:

```
$('.form-radios label').click(function() {
       var $this = $(this);

       $this.next('input').prop('checked', 'checked'); // Took the liberty of fixing this up, too.
       $this.addClass('checked');
       $this.closest('.form-radios').find('label').not(this).removeClass('checked');
});​
```

Comment: he also needs to group the radios using the name attribute.

Comment: Isn't this only for jQuery 1.6+?  I'm on 1.3.2

Comment: @jsheffers: No, `.closest()` was added in 1.3. ([Docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)) As for `prop`, just change it to `attr` like you originally had - or upgrade :)

Comment: +1 for catching that he was setting checked on the label and not the input.  I had brushed past that.